# CSS File doesn't show any snippets suggestions

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I created a custom `tailwind` snippet for `.css` file and then found out that I have no snippet suggestions in `.css` file at all.

Don't think it relates to the problem but here is tailwind custom snippet in `css.json`:

```json
"Tailwind base code": {
        "scope": "css",
        "prefix": "twb",
        "body": [
            "@tailwind base;",
            "@tailwind components;",
            "@tailwind utilities;"
            "$2",
            "@layer utilities {"
            "    $0",
            "}"
        ]
    }
```

**I tried** to install `CSS Snippets` vs code extension - **https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joy-yu.css-snippets**
to see if those snippets are visible and still nothing:

[image]

**Nevertheless** snippet I provided above is shown when I use it in `.scss` file:

[image]

**Here is** snippets vs code settings section:

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @starball extension bisect has helped me finding problematic extension. It happened to be `PostCSS Languages Support`. Now Problem is resolved

Comment: @starball actually as I mentioned above the problem is already resolved via extension bisect. You can probable post it as an answer somehow so I can mark it as an answer

Comment: I don't answer duplicate questions when I am aware that they are duplicates. Please allow your question to be closed. See [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)